# Javascript doesn't work in Android

Tags: javascript, android

it seems that javascript doesn't work in my Android browser
(my device has Android 4.0.3). I see from the browser settings
that javascript is enabled

Still, not alert shows up.

If I run the page on a desktop it works fine.
Do you know why?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head> 
<body margin=0> 
    <section data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header"></header>
        <section data-role="content" id="content">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message">
                <label for="message" id="lblmessage">Message</label>
                <a href="#" id="btnmessage" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-inline="true"></a>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <ul id="containermsg" data-role="listview"></ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer data-role="footer"></footer>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('test')
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you not delete most of that markup from your question so that we can see the offending JS statement without scrolling? Please just show the minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: does it work in the chrome browser on your android phone? if not - is there an error in the console?

Comment: are you trying to show the page in your own webView? Did you call  `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`?

Comment: no #Droidman.It's a browser